# SED substituting double character pattern with single character of the pattern

Tags: unix, sed

hi i would like to use SED (Unix environment)in order to alternatively:

- substitute double occurrence of a character with a single occurrence of the same character
- substitute single character pattern with nothing

as example consider the following string

`I want to substitute // character with / character.`

I would like `//` to become `/` and `/` to become nothing. Therefore the final string will result as:

`I want to substitute / character with  character`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may work

```
sed  's:/\(/\)\{0,1\}:\1:g'
```

Comment: +1; nicely done - to make it work on FreeBSD/OSX too, use `\{0,1\}` instead of `\{,1\}`.

Comment: Thanks for updating; `\{,n\}` appears to be a GNU `sed` extension; POSIX only mentions the _other_ shorthand form: `\{m,\}` - see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
sed -e 's: / :  :g' -e 's: // : / :g' file
```

But not as good as `1_CR`s solution

Comment: @mklement0 Understand it know.  Need to read it more carefully :)

Comment: To be explicit about what is not as good: this only works with `/` or `//` instances surrounded by spaces.